# Why is my variable changing?

Tags: javascript

I'm having some issues with my code when calling a function from another script.
When I send the data over the variable adds a 1. Is there away to get the value from the last 2 digits and remove 1 from them and then merge them into the main int again?

Where I'm calling the function: (test.js):

```
cards.getcards(76561198089544929, function(err, res, body){});
```

Inside the script with the fucntion (index.js):

```
exports.getcards = function(steamid, callback){
console.log(steamid);
}
```

Output: `76561198089544930`

**FIX**

```js
        var steamid = 76561198089544930; //This is what I got from the function.
        var toText = steamid.toString(); //convert to string
        var lastChar = toText.slice(-2); //gets last character
        var baseChars = toText.slice(0, -2);
        var lastDigit = +(lastChar); //convert last character to number
        var newlast = lastDigit - 1;
        var steamid = baseChars+newlast;
        alert(steamid);
```

Comment: Have you tried putting it as sting? It's huge number for int. And are you sure it's not float?

Comment: I don't want it as a string. I want this module to be easy to use and free of bugs and small mistakes made by the user.

Comment: Be careful `76561198089544929 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER; // true` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

Comment: Just copy that number into the console and you'll see it gets rounded. See [JavaScript Numbers](https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_numbers.asp)

Comment: @Justinas JS has no integers.

Answer (score 1):

That number is too big to fit inside a javascript Number object. You have three choices here. Either use a string to store the number, or use a library to get arbitrarily precisioned numbers, or simply make the number smaller.

Comment: You are wrong. There is another option:         var toText = steamid.toString(); //convert to string
        var lastChar = toText.slice(-2); //gets last character
        var baseChars = toText.slice(0, -2);
        var lastDigit = +(lastChar); //convert last character to number
        var newlast = lastDigit - 1;
        var steamid = baseChars+newlast;